# How to aggregate geographically segregated data by date in python?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, pandas-groupby

I am working with timeseries data that is broken down by several geographical levels (province and health region). The data are further broken down by age group. I would like to aggregate data first up to the health region, and then up to the province, depending on the need.

Sample data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date':['1/1/2022','1/1/2022','1/1/2022','1/1/2022','1/1/2022','1/1/2022','1/1/2022','1/1/2022','1/1/2022'],
             'province':[35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,],'health region':[1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3],
              'age group':[1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3],'cases':[6,1,9,7,9,0,4,2,2]})
```

Desired output when aggregating up to the health region level:

```
df_hr = pd.DataFrame({'Date':['1/1/2022','1/1/2022','1/1/2022'],
                     'province':[35,35,35],
                     'health region':[1,2,3],'cases':[16,16,8]})
```

When I use the following code:

```
df = df.groupby('health region').sum()
```

I lose dates.

When I try:

```
df =  df.groupby(['health region','Date']).sum()
```

or

```
df =  df.groupby(['health region',df['Date'].dt.date).sum()
```

I get an error `ValueError: mixed datetimes and integers in passed array`

Is there an easy way to do this? I was thinking of using a loop to split the data by health region, saving unique dates, aggregating, merging dates back, then stacking health regions back together. But I'd rather not if there is an easy way to do that.

Thank you,
i.

Comment: Please don't share images as it becomes impossible for us to reproduce your sample input at our ends. Instead please provide a reproducible example by sharing a sample input dataframe with expected output.

Comment: Do you parse `df['Date']` to datetime?

Answer (score 1):

I figured out a way how to do that.

First need to convert Date to datetime and set it as index:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df.set_index('Date',inplace = True)
```

Then I can group by region and resample data by day

```
df1 = df.groupby('health region').resample('D').sum()
```

And reset index

```
df1 = df1.reset_index()
```